# Mark as checked all child in a netsted checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nested checkboxes of this type:

```
<ul id="location-stuff">

 <li>
    <ul>
        <a class="parent_taxe_loc" rel="taxe_project_cat_48" style="cursor:pointer;">…</a>
        Argentina<input class="parent_input_taxe_loc" type="checkbox" value="48" name="loc_term"></input>
        <li id="taxe_project_cat_48" class="" style="">
            <a class="parent_city" rel="city_project_cat_450" href="#"> … </a>Buenos Aires<input type="checkbox" value="450" name="loc_term"></input>
            <ul id="city_project_cat_450" class="baca_loc" style="">
                <li>25 De Mayo <input type="checkbox" value="451" name="loc_term"></input>
                </li>
             ...
             ...
             </ul>
        </li>
     </ul></li></ul>
```

I would like that when a parent  is checked, then all children have to be marked as checked.
So I put this script jquery on the page

```
$('input[class="parent_input_taxe_loc"]').each (function () {
                $(this).bind('click change', function (){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            $(this).siblings('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                            $(this).parents('ul').siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                    } else {
                            $(this).siblings('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked', 'checked');
                    }
                });
            });
```

but for some reason does not work. The path `input[class="parent_input_taxe_loc"]` seems correct. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
$('input[class="parent_input_taxe_loc"]').on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="location-stuff">
    <li>
        <ul> <a class="parent_taxe_loc" rel="taxe_project_cat_48" style="cursor:pointer;">…</a>
Argentina
            <input class="parent_input_taxe_loc" type="checkbox" value="48" name="loc_term"></input>
            <li id="taxe_project_cat_48" class="" style=""> <a class="parent_city" rel="city_project_cat_450" href="#"> … </a>Buenos Aires
                <input type="checkbox" value="450" name="loc_term"></input>
                <ul id="city_project_cat_450" class="baca_loc" style="">
                    <li>25 De Mayo
                        <input type="checkbox" value="451" name="loc_term"></input>
                    </li>... ...</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can work same way for nested cities etc.

Comment: This solution does not works for sublocations. If I mark Buenos Aires, 25 de Mayo is not marked.

Comment: That's why i wrote "You can work same way for nested cities etc." You can set a class for cities for example.

Comment: I wondering if there a method to find all children from one parent.

Comment: this answer is the correct one. I had only to change the selector from `input[class="parent_input_taxe_loc"]` to `input[type="checkbox"]`

Answer (score 2):

```js
//if this is the solution you were looking for kindly mark this answer as correct :)
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('ul').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="location-stuff">
 <li>
    <ul>
        <a class="parent_taxe_loc" rel="taxe_project_cat_48" style="cursor:pointer;">…</a>
        Argentina<input class="parent_input_taxe_loc" type="checkbox" value="48" name="loc_term"></input>
        <li id="taxe_project_cat_48" class="" style="">
            <a class="parent_city" rel="city_project_cat_450" href="#"> … </a>Buenos Aires<input type="checkbox" value="450" name="loc_term"></input>
            <ul id="city_project_cat_450" class="baca_loc" style="">
                <li>25 De Mayo <input type="checkbox" value="451" name="loc_term"></input>
                </li>
             ...
             ...
             </ul>
        </li>
     </ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: There is a problem. The checkboxes are many. With this code when I mark eg: Buenos Aires, all the level brothers of it (eg Cordoba, Chubut...) are marked as checked.

Comment: I would like that when a parent is checked, then all children have to be marked as checked.> @emanuele I thought that was what you wanted to code to do